# python, how to fill entire row? row(i).fill = PatternFill

Tags: python

My code currently does this, I'm wondering if there is a shorter way to write this?

```
sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).fill = PatternFill(start_color='ff0000', end_color='ff0000', fill_type="solid")
sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).fill = PatternFill(start_color='ff0000', end_color='ff0000', fill_type="solid")
sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).fill = PatternFill(start_color='ff0000', end_color='ff0000', fill_type="solid")
sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).fill = PatternFill(start_color='ff0000', end_color='ff0000', fill_type="solid")
```

Comment: Which modules are you using? What is "sheet"? We need more infos!

Comment: I'm using openpyxl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop maybe?

```
for r in range(3, 7):
   sheet.cell(row = i, column = r).fill = PatternFill(start_color= 'ff0000', end_color= 'ff0000', fill_type = "solid")
```

You could also move that configuration outside the loop if you'd like, that may make configuration easier:

```
pfKwargs = {'start_color': 'ff0000', 'end_color': 'ff0000', 'fill_type': 'solid'}

for r in range(3, 7):
   sheet.cell(row = i, column = r).fill = PatternFill(**pfKwargs)
```

Or perhaps move it into a function:

```
def addFills(sheet, start = 3, count = 4, start_color='ff0000', end_color='ff0000', fill_type="solid")
     for r in range(start, start + count):
        sheet.cell(row = i, column = r).fill = PatternFill(
                                                  start_color=start_color, 
                                                  end_color=end_color, 
                                                  fill_type=fill_type)

addFills(sheet) # does the same as the above.
addFills(sheet, 1, 200) # does the same as the above, starting at 1 and ending at 201
addFills(sheet, end_color='00ff00') # Same as above only green end color.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for loop like this :

```
for col in xrange(3, 7):
    sheet.cell(row = i, column = col).fill = PatternFill(start_color= 'ff0000', end_color= 'ff0000', fill_type = "solid")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take that make your code simpler and more easy to maintain.

### Approach 1. Use meaningful variable names for your fills

You could use a loop, but sometimes you want to maintain more control over each cell. This is especially true when the formatting requirements are subject to frequent change. In cases like this, a loop is less useful and you might want something more explicit, like this:

```
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='ff0000', end_color='ff0000', fill_type="solid")
sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).fill = redFill
sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).fill = redFill
sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).fill = redFill
sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).fill = redFill
```

By using meaningful variables like `redFill`, you can make the program more maintainable. For example, later, you might want to add a `blueFill` and change just a couple of cells:

```
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='ff0000', end_color='ff0000', fill_type="solid")
blueFill = PatternFill(start_color='0000ff', end_color='0000ff', fill_type="solid")
sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).fill = blueFill
sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).fill = redFill
sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).fill = redFill
sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).fill = blueFill
```

(You might have noticed that this new format requirement just broke the loop-based solutions.)

### Approach 2. Use constants and small functions with meaningful names

This example introduces meaningful constants `RED` and `BLUE`, so that your code doesn't need to have *"magic constants"* hard-coded throughout. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

```
RED = "ff0000"
BLUE = "0000ff"
function solidFill(color):
  return PatternFill(start_color=color, end_color=color, fill_type="solid")


sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).fill = solidFill(RED)
sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).fill = solidFill(BLUE)
sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).fill = solidFill(RED)
sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).fill = solidFill(BLUE)
```

This implementation has the advantage that you just need to add a new constant and you can keep using the `solidFill` function. But, even this isn't quite as satisfying as it could be.

### Option 3. Tease out higher-meaning functions

So far, we've been trying to just write less Python code. Over time, however, that can become unmanageable--like a kid's LEGO collection stored in one big box.

Instead, if we step back and look at this from a higher perspective, we can ask, "What are we really trying to accomplish here?" The answer might look something like this code sample:

```
RED = "ff0000"
BLUE = "0000ff"

function solidFill(color):
  return PatternFill(start_color=color, end_color=color, fill_type="solid")

function fillCell(row, column, color):
  sheet.cell(row=row, column=column).fill = solidFill(color)


fillCell(i, 3, RED)
fillCell(i, 4, BLUE)
fillCell(i, 5, BLUE)
fillCell(i, 6, RED)
```

We still have our low-level function `solidFill`, which we can use in other situations that call for a **PatternFill**. And, overall, we've increased the line count in this example.

But what would happen if you needed to fill 30 different cells, instead of 4? The simple `fillCell` call is about 20 characters, compared to the original line's 108 characters. If you're manually typing this, it gets old fast. (Copy-and-paste is not really a great solution, but that's a different topic.)

### Which approach is best?

Pragmatically, maybe just pick the approach that suits your purposes today. It is easy to over-optimize code if you try to anticipate tomorrow's needs. But, if you already have a sizable codebase, go ahead and pick out the patterns, make meaningful functions, and apply them for a shorter, more readable program.